# Redirect to web page based on radio button using submit button in html

Tags: javascript, html

My webpage takes inputs from users using  a `form` with radio buttons.
Once user completes the form with all radio buttons and click submit button, it needs to redirect to web page based on the radio button selected

I have multiple fieldsets within the form, but i wanted to use only specific radio buttons for redirect purpose. so i refer the 'id' in input.

I tried onSubmit and action in the form, both doesn't seems helping.

`<form onSubmit="javascript:redirect();" method="post">`
`<form action="javascript:redirect();">`

if i use action, it simply redirects to first html page for all the radio button inputs , whereas onSubmit doesn't redirect at all

Also tried the multiple functions, but no luck yet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
    var textValue = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if(textValue == "Compassionate")
    {
        location.href = "../Results/results_empathy.html";
    }
    else if(textValue == "Meticulous")
    {
        location.href = "../Results/results_analytical.html";
    }
    else if(textValue == "Conscientious")
    {
        location.href = "../Results/results_diplomatic.html";
    }
    else
    {
        location.href = "../Results/results_creative.html";
    }
}
</script>

<form action="javascript:redirect();">

    <fieldset class="ntset">
    <legend>About Yourself</legend>
  <h4>Your Character in One Word</h4>
         <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Compassionate"><label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Compassionate</label>
     <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Meticulous"><label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Meticulous</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Conscientious"><label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Conscientious </label>
     <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Playful"><label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Playful</label><br>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="button" ></p>
    <p><input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button" ></p>

</form>
```

Also tried the following function

````
function checkAnswer(){
    var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (response == "Compassionate")
        location = '../Results/results_empathy.html';
        location.href = "../Results/results_empathy.html";
    else if (response == "Meticulous")
        location = '../Results/results_analytical.html';
        location.href = "../Results/results_analytical.html";
    else if (response == "Conscientious")
        location = '../Results/results_diplomatic.html';
        location.href = "../Results/results_diplomatic.html";    
    else if (response == "Playful")
        location = '../Results/results_creative.html';
        location.href = "../Results/results_creative.html";
    else
        location = 'wrong.html';
    return false;
}```

Expected Results are : 
If radio button selected for "Compassionate", then it has redirect to "results_empathy.html", similarly for "Meticulous" "Conscientious"
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById('answer');`, use :

`document.querySelector('input[name="habits2"]:checked').value`

See if that helps you

Comment: You're welcome! Just don't know why it got downvoted by someone else lol

Comment: Can you also help me how to populate all checkbox/radio inputs into redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

When a `form` is submitted, it will automatically redirect to the location specified in the `action` attribute. If you have a `submit` callback that tries to set `location.href` that won't work because of the nature of form submissions.

What you need to do is either not use a `submit` button (and therefore the `submit` event) and just use a regular `button` and its `click` event or you need to cancel the native `submit` event and manually control the redirect.

**NOTES:**

- With radio buttons, you need to get the value of the group, not any
  one button. Since the group all share the same name, but only one can
  be selected at a time, then the group will only ever have a single
  value. It's that value you need to check.
- You are missing your closing `fieldset` tag.
- `javascript:` isn't needed.
- `type=text/javascript` isn't needed.
- Don't set up your event handlers with HTML attributes. Do it
  separately in JavaScript.
- Don't use HTML elements because of the way they make content look.
  You are using an `h4` element in your `fieldset` but an `h4` should
  only ever be used after an `h3`. Heading tags are for creating
  sections, not for styling.

**OPTION 1: Use regular button without `submit` event:**

```html
<form action="#">

  <fieldset class="ntset">
    <legend>About Yourself</legend>
    <h1>Your Character in One Word</h1>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Compassionate">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Compassionate</label>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Meticulous">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Meticulous</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Conscientious">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Conscientious</label>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Playful">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Playful</label><br>

    <p><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button"></p>
  </fieldset>

</form>

<script>
  // Get all the element references you'll need just once
  let answer = document.querySelector("[name='habits2']");
  let submit = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
  
  // Configue event handlers in JavaScript, not with HTML attributes
  submit.addEventListener("click", redirect);
  
  function redirect() {
    if(answer.value == "Compassionate"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_empathy.html";
    }else if(textValue == "Meticulous"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_analytical.html";
    }else if(textValue == "Conscientious"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_diplomatic.html";
    }else {
        location.href = "../Results/results_creative.html";
    }
  }
</script>
```

**OPTION 2: Use a form with submit button and cancel the submit event:**

```html
<form action="#">

  <fieldset class="ntset">
    <legend>About Yourself</legend>
    <h1>Your Character in One Word</h1>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Compassionate">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Compassionate</label>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Meticulous">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Meticulous</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Conscientious">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Conscientious</label>
    <input type="radio" id="answer" name="habits2" value="Playful">
    <label class="fmt" for="habits2"> Playful</label><br>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button"></p>
  </fieldset>

</form>

<script>
  // Get all the element references you'll need just once
  let answer = document.querySelector("[name='habits2']");
  let form = document.querySelector("form");
  
  // Configue event handlers in JavaScript, not with HTML attributes
  form.addEventListener("submit", redirect);
  
  function redirect(event) {
    // Cancel the form's native reaction to a submit
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if(answer.value == "Compassionate"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_empathy.html";
    }else if(textValue == "Meticulous"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_analytical.html";
    }else if(textValue == "Conscientious"){
        location.href = "../Results/results_diplomatic.html";
    }else {
        location.href = "../Results/results_creative.html";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and modified code. I tried both methods, it doesn't seems to be working.
As soon as i click the submit, it stays same page, but i see following in url bar

http://....../register.html?Person%27s+Name=&ansName=Meticulous&Drinks=None#

Comment: I really appreciate taking the time to help me with multiple options...Thanks so much